# hide out of stock products from layered navigation in magento2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, child

I have a bought extension of many around for layered navigation with Ajax, and I have an attribute size.
Show out of stock product is enable.
Now when using the filter to let's say show only product with size Small, it still show all configurable products with child small even if the small child simple product associated is out of stock.

So what I basically want is to hide out of stock product from layered navigation even when child products

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin > Stores > configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options

Set Display Out of Stock Products to NO
[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I want, I want out of stock hide just in layered result

Comment: Any updates here?